# how do I check if an entity is the first element of a foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

Say I have a `foreach` loop.

I have to do something with the first object of the loop that I don't have to do with any of the other objects.

How do I check if the item that's currently in the loop is the first object.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There are several ways that you could do that.

1. Use a `for` loop instead
2. Set a Boolean flag
3. Use Linq to get the `list.First()` and then `foreach` over `list.Skip(1)`

Answer (score 117):

I like the Linq way, but without the Skip(1), this way you can also use it for the last item in a list and your code remains clean imho :)

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    if (items.First()==item)
        item.firstStuff();

    else if (items.Last() == item)
        item.lastStuff();

    item.otherStuff();
}
```

Comment: I don't like this approach because it's not strictly accurate. If an item is present more than once, for example, and is also the first or last item, then you'll fire the first or last condition more than once. or if some items have equality, they can fire it more than once too.

Comment: @Sahuagin Question is about testing item for is it first or not. If you clear the else if part, which means you are testing item for being only first or not, your rightful concerns will be soothed.

Answer (score 41):

Something like this:

```
bool first = true;

foreach(var item in items)
{
    if (first)
    {
        item.firstStuff();
        first = false;
    }
    item.otherStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Here's a performant solution:

```
using (var erator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (erator.MoveNext())
    {
        DoActionOnFirst(erator.Current);

        while (erator.MoveNext())
            DoActionOnOther(erator.Current);
    }
}
```

EDIT: And here's a LINQ one:

```
if (enumerable.Any())
    {
        DoActionOnFirst(enumerable.First());

        foreach (var item in enumerable.Skip(1))
            DoActionOnOther(item);
    }
```

EDIT: If the actions on the items have signatures assignable to `Func<TItem, TResult>`, you can do:

```
enumerable.Select((item, index) => index == 0 ? GetResultFromFirstItem(item) : GetResultFromOtherItem(item));
```

Comment: While this technically satisfies the requirements, it is significantly less readable than using a 'first' flag to indicate as others have posted.

Comment: @ Paul: It is more efficient, and I don't see why it is significantly less readable.

Comment: Not sure how this is more efficient when compared to using a 'first' flag.

Comment: @Babar With this solution there is no need to evaluate a variable on each iteration

Comment: For the LINQ answer this should be the correct answer as it is more elegant than using a flag.

Answer (score 6):

```
bool first = true;
foreach(var foo in bar)
{
  if (first)
  {
    // do something to your first item
    first = false;
  }
  // do something else to the rest
}
```

Comment: grr, not quick enough! didn't see geofftnz's post.

Comment: it's the StackOverflow patented easy-question race :)

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion this is the simplest way

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if((list.IndexOf(item) == 0)
    {
        // first
    }
    // others
}
```

Comment: It may be the simplest way, but it is very expensive. If list is an arbitrary `IEnumerable` the complexity is within O(n) which is a lot of overhead to be performed in  each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
bool IsFirst = true;

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    if (IsFirst)
    {
        // do some thing
        IsFirst = false;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't think of anything but

```
var processedFirst = false;
foreach(var x in items) {
    if(!processedFirst) {
        ProcessFirst(x);
        processedFirst = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a general solution for getting index along with each object in an array. Should work testing if it's the first.

```
        List<String> entries = new List<string>();
        entries.Add("zero");
        entries.Add("one");
        entries.Add("two");

        Dictionary<int, String> numberedEntries = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        int i = 0;
        entries.ForEach(x => numberedEntries.Add(i++, x));
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, String> pair in numberedEntries) {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ": " + pair.Value);
        }
```

In this setup, the Key of the KeyValuePair is the index and the value is the object at that index, in my example a string, but any object could be placed there. It adds a little overhead, but can be used to determine any object in the list's index when needed.

Comment: Smells like Python's dict.__items__

I like it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also write:

```
foreach ((T item, bool isFirst) in items.Select((item, index) => (item, index == 0)))
{
    if (isFirst)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you need this a lot, you can write an extension method to replace the Select and make your code shorter.

Comment: I was looking for a type I'd used long ago, IndexedEnumerable. https://gist.github.com/jeremysimmons/545de72e0447c55b9ae5ede910d5129b. I do appreciate your short version though.